# Pass references to javascript functions that use jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a number of links that, when clicked, are going to make some divs show and others not.

```
function slideup(whichdiv)
{
    $("#div1").hide();
    $("#div2").slideDown(2000);
    $(whichdiv)slideDown(2000);
}
```

The function above works if the 3rd line is missing ... how do you pass a reference to a div to a jquery function? How do you get it to know which of the divs is 'whichdiv'?

Comment: what are you passing in as 'whichdiv' in `slideup` that is causing the error?

Comment: um... missing `.` on the third one?

Comment: There could be any number of problems. You're going to need to provide an example on jsfiddle for any real help.

Comment: @Doorknob - Wow - 1000 points to you.

Comment: it is amazing how many questions here could be solved by simply pasting the code to jsfiddle and clicking the jshint button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
function slideup(whichdiv)
{
    $("#div1").hide();
    $("#div2").slideDown(2000);
    whichdiv.slideDown(2000);
}
```

And call it like this:

```
slideup($('#someDiv'))
```

If you want to do it the current way, you're going to have to add the missing `.` on the third one:

```
$(whichdiv)slideDown(2000); //where is the .
```

Comment: The missing . was a typo. I was calling it like this:
<span onclick="slideup('div2')>Slide Div 2</span>

which was not working. Your way works (but I'm sure you know that). Thank you for your help.